# How do I visualize a MySQL Nested Set?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm following the nested set model as represented here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

I have hierarchical data, effectively, a bunch of different graphs with edges/nodes, and am looking to visualize it. I understand the concept of the nested set, but am not sure how I know the parent/child relationships of each node without running an excessive amount of queries (performance).

I'm attempting to use something like http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html from visjs to create the graph.

But visjs wants the data sets in the following formats:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // create an array with nodes
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
  ]);

  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>
```

Is there a way I can run a single query or an efficient function that will return the data so that I know:

Node 1 (lft 1, rgt 8) has childs Node 2 (2,3) and Node 3 (4,7)

Node 3 has child Node 4 (5,6)

```
    Node 1
      /\
Node 2  Node 3
          | 
        Node 4
```

I can get the full tree, or I can do the indented thing,

Based on the visjs example, I am unsure how to efficiently know each node and its edges.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "visualize."

In any programming language you choose, a directed graph can be represented as a set of node pairs, each of which represents a parent and a child.  Nodes with no parents are sources, while nodes with no children are sinks.  There are umpteen well-known and widely published algorithms for walking a cutset of a tree and evaluating all possible walks, circuits, etc.